# Hangout Chat API authentication fails with Default Service account

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-hangouts

I'm testing the new Google Chat bot that should post messages asynchronously, thus I must use GoogleCredentials to authenticate requests.

It works perfectly fine when I use `GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()` while working locally, but when I deploy the bot to Cloud Run it stops.

**idiomatic secure way (does not work)**

The HangoutsChat is created the following way:

```java
var credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
                                   .createScoped(CHAT_BOT_SCOPE);
var credentialsAdapter = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);
var chat = new HangoutsChat.Builder(
    GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
    credentialsAdapter)
    .setApplicationName(BOT_NAME)
    .build();
```

So in order to work locally, I set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and point it to the service account key like this: `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./credentials/adc.json`. While in the cloud environment I expect the same service account to just work, but if not set explicitly from the file, the credentials throw `insufficientPermissions` error with `PERMISSION_DENIED`.

**workaround (works fine)**

As a workaround, I'm creating credentials from the service account stored in Secret Manager like this:

```java
var serviceAccount = Secrets.chatServiceAccount();
var credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(streamFrom(serviceAccount))
                               .createScoped(CHAT_BOT_SCOPE);
var credentialsAdapter = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);
var chat = new HangoutsChat.Builder(
    GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
    credentialsAdapter)
    .setApplicationName(BOT_NAME)
    .build();
return chat;


private static InputStream streamFrom(String data) {
return new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
}
```

The question is: is anyone able to use default credentials for HangoutsChat API? Is it even possible or I am missing something here?

Comment: By default, Cloud Run runs with a service account in your GCP project named "Compute Engine default service account". If you have already created a custom service account, make sure you're deploying Cloud Run app with the custom account using `--service-account` option.

Comment: @AhmetB, yep, I know that. It does not help. The API still does not work even if I supply custom service account. It works fine only if I use a particular .json key.